# Create a map of classes

Tags: typescript

```js
// RoleManager.ts
import RoleObject from "../interfaces/guild/RoleObject";
import AvatarObject from "../interfaces/user/AvatarObject";

const RoleManager = class {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    color: number;
    hoisted: boolean;
    icon: AvatarObject;
    position: number;
    managed: boolean;
    mentionable: boolean;

    constructor(role: RoleObject) {
        this.id = role.id;
        this.name = role.name;
        this.color = role.color;
        this.hoisted = role.hoist;
        this.icon = {
            hash: role.icon,
            url: role.icon ? `https://discord.com/assets/${role.icon}.svg` : null,
        };
        this.position = role.position;
        this.managed = role.managed;
        this.mentionable = role.mentionabale;
    }
}

export default RoleManager;
```

```js
// GuildManager.ts
import GuildObject from '../interfaces/guild/GuildObject';
import RoleManager from './RoleManager';

const GuildManager = class {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    ownerID: string;
    roles: Map<string, typeof RoleManager>
    emojis: Map<string, typeof EmojiManager>

    constructor(guild: GuildObject) {
        this.id = guild.id;
        this.name = guild.name;
        this.ownerID = guild.owner_id;
        // this.owner = new UserManager(this.ownerID); << Implement later
        this.roles = new Map();
        this.emojis = new Map();

        guild.roles.forEach(role => this.roles.set(role.id, new RoleManager(role)));
        guild.emojis.forEach(emoji => this.roles.set(emoji.id, new EmojiManager(emoji)));
    }
}

export default GuildManager;
```

I'm trying to create a map which is <string, instance of a class>. However, when I do `roles: Map<string, RoleManager>` it throws an error saying `RoleManager` isn't a type and tells me to use `typeof`, but in doing that I get this error:

```
Argument of type 'RoleManager' is not assignable to parameter of type 'typeof RoleManager'.
  Property 'prototype' is missing in type 'RoleManager' but required in type 'typeof RoleManager'.
```

How can I make the map accept <string, instance of RoleManager>

Comment: You should probably include the contents of "./RoleManager.ts", because we don't actually know what that class looks like or how it's being exported

Comment: Consider using `Record<string, RoleManager>` instead of a Map

Comment: Assuming RoleManager is a class

Comment: I tried using Record and it throws same error:

Comment: 'RoleManager' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof RoleManager'?

Comment: @Ben I added RoleManager.ts

Comment: I didn't find an evidence of that, but this can be caused by the class expression instead of class declaration. Try to use `class Name {` syntax and see what happens

Comment: that doesn't work

Comment: sorry it didn't work, i compiled the wrong file @KonradLinkowski